# Mybatis Spring - Transaction Management

Tags: spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Say I have the following code. Please review. I have added my questions below:

Mybatis Config:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyMybatisConfiguration{

     @Bean
     public DataSource datasource(){
        //configure some db
     }

     @Bean
     public SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory(){
         SqlSessionFactoryBean ssfb = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
         ssfb.setDataSource(dataSource())
         return ssfb;
     }

     @Bean
     public SqlSessionTemplate sessionTemplate(){
         return new SqlSessionTemplate(sessionFactory());
     }


 }
```

Service Layer:

```
@Service
public class MyService{

    public MyDao myDao;

    public MyService(MyDao myDao){
       this.myDao = myDao;
    }

    public addItems(List<Item> items){

       for(Item item : items)
       {
           myDao.insertItem(item);
       }  

    }

    public addItemsBulk(List<String> items){

        myDao.insertItems(items)

    }

}
```

Dao Layer:

```
 @Repository
 public class MyDao {

      private SqlSessionTemplate tmp;

      @Autowired
      public MyDao(SqlSessionTemplate tmp){
          this.tmp = tmp;
      }


      public insertItem(Item item){
         sst.insert("insertItem", item)
      }

      public insertItems(List<Item> items){
         sst.insert("insertItems", items)
      }

    }
```

I am assuming that in the above example, if someone called this method

```
public addItems(List<Item> items){

  for(Item item : items)
  {
       myDao.insertItem(item);
  }  

}
```

It would be less performant than calling:

```
 public addItemsBulk(List<String> items){

     myDao.insertItems(items)

 }
```

...because **for each iteration of the for loop** the following would occur:

> 1. Session Template uses Session Factory
> 2. Session Factory creates Session, opening connection.
> 3. Session Factory creates Transaction
> 4. Session Factory executes insert
> 5. Session Factory commits transaction
> 6. Session Factory closes session

^So in this example **I am assuming** that in the case of the method containing the for loop there would be multiple sessions, one for each insert, with a transaction per session.

---

Now what would happen if on top of the MyService class, I added the **@Transactional** annotation?

I am assuming that the performance would be identical and that this would be the order of events in both cases:

> 1. Session Template uses Session Factory
> 2. Session Factory creates Session, opening connection.
> 3. Session Factory creates Transaction
> 4. Session Factory executes ALL insert statements
> 5. Session Factory commits transaction
> 6. Session Factory closes session

^So in this example **I am assuming** that in the case of the method containing the for loop there would be one session and one transaction.

Am I correct in my reasoning or is it flawed?

Comment: As I know when you persist items one by one it call `session.flush()` on each item, but when you use bulk insertion it will flush the session at the end. and It is the reason of why bulk insertion has better performance than one by one

Answer (score 0):

You question is not related to @Transactional but the usage of Mybatis' Executor.BATCH (which is the equivalent of preparedStatement.executeBatch() )

Compare the difference between your original solution and a setup below:

Add ExecutorType.BATCH to SqlSessionTemplate:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyMybatisConfiguration{

     ...

     @Bean
     public SqlSessionTemplate sessionTemplate(){
         return new SqlSessionTemplate(sessionFactory(), ExecutorType.BATCH);
     }

 }
```

Declare a method flushStatements:

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {
      ....
      public flush(){
         sst.flushStatements();
      }
}
```

Add the flush to addItems

```
public addItems(List<Item> items){

  for(Item item : items)
  {
       myDao.insertItem(item);
       myDao.flush();
  }  

}
```